# Provide different TreeCell conditionally in CellFactory

Tags: javafx, treeview, javafx-2, custom-cell

I have a treeview in which the cells must display different information according to the real implementation of the [TreeItem's value](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeItem.html#getValue%28%29).

My domain model looks like:

[image: Domain model]

It seemed natural to me to split the behaviour of "how to display a Task in a cell" or "how to display a Group in a cell" in two different classes.

```
public abstract class ComponentTreeCell<T extends Component> extends TreeCell<T>
{
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty)
    {
        //Some common logic...
    }
}

public class GroupTreeCell extends ComponentTreeCell<Group>
{
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Group item, boolean empty)
    {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        //Some group-specific-logic
    }    
}

public class TaskTreeCell extends ComponentTreeCell<Task>
{
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Task item, boolean empty)
    {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        //Some task-specific-logic
    }    
}
```

The following controller class contains a [TreeView](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeView.html) where I set the CellFactory.

```
public class Controller implements Initializable
{
    @FXML
    private TreeView<Component> treeview;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle bundle)
    {
        treeview.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<Component>, TreeCell<Component>>()
        {
            @Override
            public TreeCell<Component> call(TreeView<Component> arg0)
            {
                if(/* stuck */ instanceof Group)
                {
                    return new GroupTreeCell();
                }
                else if(/* stuck */ instanceof Task)
                {
                    return new TaskTreeCell();
                }
                else
                {
                    return new DefaultTreeCell();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But here I get stuck at the moment to decide  which kind of cell I have to return. Indeed I only have in parameter the related [TreeView](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeView.html) and **not the related [TreeItem](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeItem.html)** !

It seems to me like a kind of weakness of JavaFX. Why JavaFX gives the full TreeView to the user when you only need to retrieve one TreeCell ??

Is there a way to do it in this manner or do I have to implement the 2 different behaviour in the same custom TreeCell implementation ?

```
public class ComponentTreeCell extends TreeCell<Component>
{
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Component item, boolean empty)
        {
            //Some common logic...

            if(item instanceof Group)
            {
                //Group-specific logic...
            }
            else if(item instanceof Task)
            {
                //Task-specific logic...
            }
            else
            {
                //Default logic...
            }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why JavaFX gives the full TreeView to the user when you only need to retrieve one TreeCell ??

Because there isn't a 1-1 relationship between `TreeItem`s and `TreeCell`s: the `TreeView` will create only a small number of `TreeCell`s (even if the tree has a very large number of items). The `TreeCell`s are reused to display different `TreeItem`s, for example if some nodes are expanded/collapsed, or if the user scrolls.

It is done this way for performance. The actual cells that provide the rendering are quite large objects: they are UI components and carry CSS styling etc with them. The actual data displayed, i.e. the `TreeItem`s are relatively lightweight; often they are just simple wrappers for `String`s. So this mechanism allows to have `TreeView`s with huge amounts of data that do not impose a huge burden on performance. Creating a `TreeCell` for every `TreeItem` would not allow this.

Because of this, the `TreeCell` you provide from the factory has to be able to handle any `TreeItem` that might be given to it by the `TreeView`. For example, as the user changes the items that are displayed (by expanding/collapsing or by scrolling), a `TreeCell` instance that was previously displaying a `Task` might be used to display a `Group`. This is the purpose of the `updateItem(...)` method; it is called when the `TreeCell` is reused.

This means your setup simply won't work. You basically need the `TreeCell<Component>` implementation in your last code example. You could of course factor the configuration into separate classes if you like, something like:

```
public class ComponentTreeCell extends TreeCell<Component>
{
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Component item, boolean empty)
    {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        CellConfiguratorFactory.getConfigurator(item).configure(this, item, empty);
    }

}
```

Factory:

```
public class CellConfiguratorFactory {

    private static CellConfigurator<Task> taskCellConfigurator ;
    private static CellConfigurator<Group> groupCellConfigurator ;
    private static CellConfigurator<Component> defaultCellConfigurator ;

    private static CellConfigurator getConfigurator(Component item) {
        if (item instanceof Task) {
            if (taskCellConfigurator == null) {
                taskCellConfigurator = new TaskCellConfigurator();
            }
            return taskCellConfigurator ;
        } else if (item instanceof Group) {
            if (groupCellConfigurator == null) {
                groupCellConfigurator = new GroupCellConfigurator();
            }
            return groupCellConfigurator ;
        } else {
            if (defaultCellConfigurator == null) {
                defaultCellConfigurator = new DefaultCellConfigurator();
            }
            return defaultCellConfigurator ;
        }
    }
}
```

(Note you can afford to assume the factory is only ever used from a single thread, since everything will happen on the FX Application Thread.)

And then

```
public interface CellConfigurator<T extends Component> {
    public void configureCell(ComponentTreeCell cell, T item, boolean empty);
}
```

with, for example,

```
public class TaskCellConfigurator implements CellConfigurator<Task> {
    public void configureCell(TreeCell<Component> cell, Task item, boolean empty) {
        // task-specific implementation...
    }
}
```

However, I'm not sure the additional structure is worth the effort here.

Comment: It could seem a bit overkill at the moment (even more considering my specific logic consists on only a few lines of code) but your solution is evolutive and offers the abstraction level I wanted. Btw, making use of `instanceof`outside of a factory is for me a code smell, so I'll go with your solution.

Comment: "_as the user changes the items that are displayed (by expanding/collapsing or by scrolling), a TreeCell instance that was previously displaying a Task might be used to display a Group_".  Great answer that remind me I omitted this fact and thus, was limiting my comprehension of `updateItem`.

Comment: Could you guys please post the full running code somewhere at pastebin.com? I can't get it together.